# Given a sequence $n_{i+1} = f(n_i)$ with $f$ a polynomial of degree m. Any way to get the index $i$ of a sequence element $v$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, sequence-of-function, chebyshev-polynomials

A sequence
$$n_{i+1} = f_m(n_i)$$
with $f_m$ a polynomial of degree $m$. 
With this also $n_i$ is a polynomial:

$$n_i=\sum_{j=0}^{m\cdot i} a_jx^j$$

If $n_1$ has polynomial degree $m$ then the degree of $n_i$ is $i$-times higher.

Given
$$n_0= c \text{ , (constant)} >=0 \in \mathbb{R}$$
and a sequence value $v$. Is there any way to compute index $i$ with 
$$n_i=v$$
?

Or is the only way to compute all sequence elements until $n_i$ equal with $v$?

---

(Especialy interested for $f$ a [Chebyshev polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) (first kind))

Comment: OK, modifying a question substantially (like your "$n_i \ne n_{i+1}$" addition to the problem) is considered rude, because it makes answers already presented look stupid, when the actual fault was in not asking the right question in the first place. It also, in this case, doesn't actually fix the problem: consider $f(x) = 1-x$, with $n_0 = 1$. Then $n_i = 0$ for $i$ even, and $n_i = 1$ for $i$ odd, and you still can't determine $i$ from $n_i$.

Comment: And adding " is not small" doesn't help either, because you can take $()=(1−)^{200}$, and still bounce between $0$ and $1$. Darned chameleon questions...I should know better. Perhaps others, reading these comments, will be warned in advance.

Comment: true about the repeating but that's actually what I'm looking for. Will do some rephrasing. Deleted the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no, esp. if the constant term is of the polynomial is zero. Consider the example where $m = 2$ and the polynomial $p(x)$ is $p(x) = x^2 - x$. For $n_0 = 1$, you get $n_1 = n_2 = \ldots = 0$. So if I tell you that $n_i = 0$ and ask you "What's $i$?" the answer is "1, or 2, or 3, or ...", i.e., the question doesn't even have a well-defined answer.

More generally, if $c$ happens to be a fixed point of the polynomial $p$, then the question has no answer; the same goes if $c$ is in the preimage of a fixed point, or the preimage of the preimage of a fixed point, etc.

Since every polynomial except for $p(x) = x + k$,  ($k \ne 0$) has fixed points, the problem in general has no solution.

In the very special case of $p(x) = x + k$, if you know that $n_i = v$, then you know that $c + k \cdot i = v$, and you can compute $i$ via $i = \frac{v-c}{k}$.

Not very interesting, of course, but at least it's a case where the question has an answer.

Comment: ty for response. Missed something in question description with $n_i \neq n_{i+1}$. The actual question is more special. I tried to make a more general first.